# 502 Bad Gateway => https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

the last hour we recieve "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)" when trying to load forge viewer.

https://health.autodesk.com/ does not indicate any outage.

Authentication and datamangement seems fine.

Any update?

Comment: Sorry about the problem. The team is working on resolving the issue. I cannot promise a deadline yet.

Comment: It has just started working for me.
Could you please give it a try?

Comment: working fine now, thx